# How to tackle Dragging & Rearranging of Heading Items in nextjs 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

So here is the thing.

I need to move around headings. Each heading is a different component. When clicked & dragged it can move around. We can rearrange all headings.

any h2 headings like How 3D Printers Work can become h3 if it is moved & place under any H2 heading.
Similarly any h3 heading can become h2 heading if we pull out & place it on the same vertical line as other h2.

[image]

This seems quite complex to make.

Apart from it every headings have separate operation which are triggered when we click on them.

Any Suggestion on this is appreciated.

Thanks